# Getting a type mismatch exception in my java code

Tags: java

Getting error when reading the 3rd element. That is while pt variable from the terminal it is returning type mismatch error i cant seem to understand why cause i declared a string variable st and used nextLine() to read from the terminal

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TravelAgencies[] ta = new TravelAgencies[4];
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
        {
            int r=s.nextInt();
             System.out.println(r);
            String an=s.nextLine();
             System.out.println(an);
            String pt=s.nextLine();
             System.out.println(pt);
            int p=s.nextInt();
              System.out.println(p);
            boolean ff=s.nextBoolean();
             System.out.println(ff);
            ta[i]=new TravelAgencies(r, an, pt, p, ff);
        }
        int max=findAgencyWithHighestPackagePrice(ta);
        System.out.println(max);
        
        int regNo=s.nextInt();
        
        String pac=s.next();
        
        TravelAgencies rs=agencyDetailsForGivenIdAndType(ta,regNo,pac);
        if(rs!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(rs.agencyName+"\n"+rs.price);
        }
        else
        System.out.println(rs);
        s.close();
        
    }
```

```
error
123
123

abhi
abhi
agency
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Probsolving.Solution.main(Solution.java:19)
```

Comment: You need to complete reading lines. nextInt() will not read entire line hence need to add one more empty line to read nextLine(). You better move to _BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))_ instead of scanner which will have a cleaner way to read input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,I would like to point out that you have tagged this question as `compiler-errors` which isn't your case. This is a Runtime error you are getting.

Secondly, coming to your code inside the `for` loop:

```
      int r = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println(r);
      String an = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println(an);
      String pt = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println(pt);
      int p = s.nextInt();
      System.out.println(p);
      boolean ff = s.nextBoolean();
      System.out.println(ff);
```

**Clearly the scanner expects first an Integer, then a String , then a String, then an Integer and lastly a boolean. If you make any alteration while entering the input, you gonna get InputMismatchException.**(Especially when you give a String for an Integer or an Integer for a Boolean).

**What is happening in your case is that, when you hit `Enter` after entering 123, Java is taking that newline character `\n` as part of second String. That's because the Scanner.nextInt method does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting "Enter," and so the call to Scanner.nextLine returns after reading that newline.**

Now since Java cannot case a 'agency' to an Integer, it is giving InputMismatchException.

The way to solve this, is by having something like this:

```
    int r = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(r);
    s.nextLine();
    String an = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(an);
    String pt = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(pt);
    int p = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println(p);
    s.nextLine();
    boolean ff = s.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println(ff);
```

i.e by putting a scanner.nextLine() call after each scanner.nextInt()  to consume the newline.

Or you can read the integer as a string and then just do a Integer.parseInt(..).